# Change wagtail admin form fields based on user input

Tags: wagtail

I've got a model called 'Block', which has multiple fields:

- type. This is a dropdown where you can select 3 options.
- URL
- Search

Based on the type field, the URL or Search must be shown.
The search field needs to preform a search using a variable: API_HOST.
I've written JS to do make the form dynamic and I've extended the wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html template to inject the JS. 
However, I'm not sure how to pass the API_HOST (defined in dev.py) down to the template.

dev.py

```
API_HOST = "http://localhost:8000/"
```

wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html:

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html" %}
{% block extra_js %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <script>
        var api_host = "{{api_url}}";
        console.log("api_host:", api_host);
    </script>
    <script src="/static/js/blocks_hook.js">
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

blocks_hook.js

```
$(function () {
        var $type = $('#id_type');
        var $search = $('#id_search');
        var $url = $('#id_url');
        var api = new API(api_host);

        hide($search);
        hide($url);

        $type.on('change', function(){
            if ($type.val() == 'search') {
                 show($search);
                 hide($url);
                 api.getProduct(function(product){
                      // .. do something with the product
                 });
            } else if($type.val() == 'url') {
                 show($url);
                 hide($search);
            }
});
```

How should I approach this situation?

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Thanks for that remark. I added the code.

Comment: I need the code of dev.py mainly form where the **wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html** template is getting rendered. Please post the code of dev.py.

Comment: dev.py is a configuration file, consisting of nothing but constants. Note that `wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html ` overrides the default edit page of wagtail. The render method itself is specified in Wagtail.

Comment: I used the following guide to extend (override) the template: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html#extending-the-login-form. The render method (`def edit(...`) of edit.html is part of Wagtail (under `wagtail.wagtailadmin.views.pages`) and not part of my project (dev.py or another file). Direct link to wagtail code: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/pages.py#L293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using the `insert_editor_js` [hook mechanism](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html), provided by Wagtail.

Make sure the variable you're passing in the method (@hooks.register) is actually present in your configuration file or else the hooks system crashes without any actionable debug information.